# display a form just in a particular case using control structure

Tags: php

I'm a beginner in PHP, I am working on a carpooling website and I want to display a form in the user account only if he didn't enter his car yet here is my code and unfortunately it didn't work and I haven't got any error on my screen. Please help me if you can !!

```
 <div id="edit-settings" class="tab-pane">
           <?php  $user_id=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
            $res = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car where $user_id');
                              $get_total = $res->fetchColumn();
                                 if($get_total==0){
                            echo 'please enter a car by filling the form below'; ?>



                                            <form action="car.php" method="post">
                                            <br />
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">
            Brand * &nbsp;
        </label>
        <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="Brand *" name="brand" maxlength="64" required="">
        <br />
    <br />  
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">
            Model * &nbsp;
        </label>
        <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="Model *" name="model" maxlength="64" required="">
        <br /><br />
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">
            Confort * &nbsp;
        </label>
        <select id="lst_confort" class="span4" name="confort">
                <option value="Basique">Basic</option>
                <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                <option value="Confortable">Confortable</option>
                <option value="Luxe">Luxary</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">
            Color * &nbsp;
        </label>
        <select id="lst_confort" class="span4" name="couleur">
                <option value="0" selected> choose a color</option>     
             <option value="0"> white</option>                           
             <option value="1">black</option>
             <option value="2">blue</option>
             <option value="3"> Red</option>
             <option value="4"> Orange </option>
             <option value="5"> Green</option>
             <option value="6"> Yellow </option>

             </select> 
            <br /><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">
            Nb places * &nbsp;
        </label>
        <select name="places" id="lst_NbPlaces" class="span2" required="">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
            </select>
            <br />
    <br />


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                Submit</button>

                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label class="text-info">
                * required field
            </label>



        </form>
        <?php } else {
                  echo "You have already entered car !";
              }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car where $user_id
```

This is in single quotes, so it is interpreted as exactly what you see above; `$user_id` is seen as literal text, not a variable. That is not a valid query. I suspect you mean something like

```
$res = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car where user_id = ' . $user_id);
```

(Change `user_id` to match your column name as needed.)

Note that this is **extremely** vulnerable to SQL injection and is therefore entirely unsafe for real-world use.

Also, in the future, you can try checking the database errors and logs to determine what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my problem, I get your point, you're right, I tried it and it didn't Work! I think now the problem is not on the query anymore.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\mywebsite\setting.php on line 557

Comment: Well, there you go. `$db` is not an object. You haven't posted enough code to diagnose that problem, but something's wrong in how you connect to your database.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the problem is resolved now.
the problem was that I didn't import my config file to setting.php by adding <?php require_once "config.php"; ?> on the top of setting.php the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error:

```
        $res = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car where $user_id');
                                                         ^---
```

You have no comparison, so in effect you're doing

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE true
```

and are counting ALL records in the table. As soon as you had one user enter a car, ALL users were treated as having cars. Perhaps you want something more like

```
        $res = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car where user = $user_id');
                                                          ^^^^^^^
```